# sql to obtain name from another table

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables

TABLE `buy_sim` (`id_buy` ,`id_client`,`date_buy`,`total_sims`)
TABLE `clients` (`id_client` ,`name_client`,`lastname_cliente`,`age`)

when i do a select * from buy_sim i get something like that:

```
|id_buy | id_client | date_buy  | total_sim |

|1      |     10    |2014-02-20 | 3         |

|2      |     8     |2014-02-21 | 4         |
```

How can I get client_name in the query? i tried
 `select *,name_cliente from buy_sim,clients` 
 
but the result is not the expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT sim.*, client.name_client
FROM buy_sim As sim INNER JOIN clients As client 
ON sim.id_client = client.id_client
```

This is based on the following assumptions:

- `id_client` is the common field between them
- `INNER JOIN` seems like a good choice as it will return all records where `id_client` is common between `sim` table and `client` table

More about [MySQL JOINS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)